# SKLEARN // Combine GridsearchCV with column transform and pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am struggling with a machine learning project, in which I am trying to combine :

- a sklearn column transform to apply different transformers to my numerical and categorical features
- a pipeline to apply my different transformers and estimators
- a `GridSearchCV` to search for the best parameters.

As long as I fill-in the parameters of my different transformers manually in my pipeline, the code is working perfectly. 
But as soon as I try to pass lists of different values to compare in my gridsearch parameters, I am getting all kind of invalid parameter error messages.

Here is my code :

**First I divide my features into numerical and categorical**

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


numerical_features=make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)
cat_features=make_column_selector(dtype_exclude=np.number)
```

**Then I create 2 different preprocessing pipelines for numerical and categorical features:**

```
numerical_pipeline= make_pipeline(KNNImputer())
cat_pipeline=make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
```

**I combined both into another pipeline, set my parameters, and run my `GridSearchCV` code**

```
model=make_pipeline(preprocessor, LinearRegression() )

params={
    'columntransformer__numerical_pipeline__knnimputer__n_neighbors':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}

grid=GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=params,scoring = 'r2',cv=10)
cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(grid, X, y, cv=cv,scoring='r2')
```

I tried different ways to declare the paramaters, but never found the proper one. I always get an "invalid parameter" error message.

Could you please help me understanding what went wrong?

Really a lot of thanks for your support, and take good care!

Comment: You've omitted your definition of `preprocessor`. Try `grid.get_params()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you might have defined `preprocessor` as the following,

```
preprocessor = Pipeline([('numerical_pipeline',numerical_pipeline),
                        ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline)])
```

then you need to change your param name as following:

`pipeline__numerical_pipeline__knnimputer__n_neighbors`

but, there are couple of other problems with the code:

1. you don't have to call `cross_val_score` after performing `GridSearchCV`. Output of GridSearchCV itself would have the cross validation result for each combination of hyper parameters.
2. `KNNImputer` would not work when you data is having string data. You need to apply `cat_pipeline` before `num_pipeline`.

## Complete example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
import pandas as pd  # doctest: +SKIP
X = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'London', 'Paris', np.nan],
                  'rating': [5, 3, 4, 5]})  # doctest: +SKIP

y = [1,0,1,1]

from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


numerical_features=make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)
cat_features=make_column_selector(dtype_exclude=np.number)

numerical_pipeline= make_pipeline(KNNImputer())
cat_pipeline=make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),
                            OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))
preprocessor = Pipeline([('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline),
                        ('numerical_pipeline',numerical_pipeline)])
model=make_pipeline(preprocessor, LinearRegression() )

params={
    'pipeline__numerical_pipeline__knnimputer__n_neighbors':[1,2]
}


grid=GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=params,scoring = 'r2',cv=2)

grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and highly detailed feedback. This was really helpfull and is working perfectly well now. To create the preprocessor pipeline, I used make_pipeline instead of pipeline, and it seems this was the bottleneck. Thanks also for the tips regarding the cat_pipeline and numerical_pipeline. I thought that as the column trnasform was allowing different preprocessing, their order wasn't a matter.   Once again thanks a lot, and have a nice day!

Comment: The order of ColumnTransformer transformers doesn't matter. This answer doesn't include a ColumnTransformer, but another pipeline.

Comment: Ya right. Here using columntransformer wouldn't be useful because we have to apply ohe before knn imputer

Comment: @Venkatachalam : There is one other elements I do not understand.  in my numerical features, I would like to add additionnal transformers like follow : numerical_pipeline= make_pipeline(KNNImputer(),preprocessing.StandardScaler(),PolynomialFeatures())      But I didn't found the proper way to test the polynomial features in the gridsearchCV parameters. Following your guidence, I added : 'pipeline__numerical_pipeline__polynomialfeatures__degree':[2,3,4]    But seems this is not working. Could you please help me in this case also? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, could u ask this as a separate question with more details?

Comment: But where do numerical_features and cat_features come into the picture later? After defining which columns belong to which type, one should to instruct the respective pipelines to work on the specific feature types.