# What is the difference between ColumnTransformer and make_ColumnTransformer

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Please explain the difference between scikit-learn's ColumnTransformer and make_Column_transformer. Also, where to use what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such major difference between the two. They both give the same result.
as you can see in docs `ColumnTransformer` uses a list of a tuple with a name and make_column_transformer is just a tuple without a name. Name given to tuple is helpful when we use `Gridsearchcv` or `Randomsearchcv`, the estimator in these can be nested pipelines of transformers and classifier and a regressor if we went to give the param_grid to them, then we can use the name of that tuple. You can see in the StackOverflow question nested pipelines and `ColumnTransformer` in `Gridsearchcv` and how naming is helpful. Generally, I use make_columns_transformer if I don't have to use `Gridseachcv`.

[sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467815/how-to-access-columntransformer-elements-in-gridsearchcv)

Answer (score 3):

This is well described in the Sklearn API:

This is a shorthand for the ColumnTransformer constructor; it does not require, and does not permit, naming the transformers. Instead, they will be given names automatically based on their types. It also does not allow weighting with transformer_weights.