# How do I setup my pipeline for GridsearchCV if I have a text features and a numerical feature?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline, countvectorizer

I'm trying to do a classification with a text feature and numerical feature.

I'll like to run CountVectorizer on my text, and passing the sparse matrix output with my numerical feature to my classifier, and then run a gridsearchcv.

This is my failed attempt at trying to setup a pipeline for gridsearchcv.

I've referenced this : [How to access ColumnTransformer elements in GridSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467815/how-to-access-columntransformer-elements-in-gridsearchcv) , but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

edit: got it to work with 'make column transformer'.

```
# X_train contains 2 columns, ['text','num']
# y_train contains 1 column, ['label']

word_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('cvec',CountVectorizer())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer (transformers = [('wt',word_transformer,['text'])],
remainder = 'passthrough')

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor',preprocessor),
    ('RBC', RandomForestClassifier())
])

pipe_params = {
    'preprocessor__wt__cvec__max_features': [1500,2000,3000],
    'RBC__max_features':['sqrt', 'log2']
}

gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, 
                  param_grid=pipe_params, 
                  cv=5) # 5-fold cross-validation.

gs.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: What's going wrong?

Comment: It seems you have solved your own question (as per the edit you have posted). Voting to close the question.

Comment: @Ben Reiniger I'll add my error message after work. Not sure if it's a syntax error. But it seemed to be solved with 'make column transformer' :https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html